# How to setup alerts for two metrics having same threshold value in one monitor in datadog?

Tags: datadog

I am trying to set the threshold limit to `2` errors for my two resources `abc.pqr` and `abc.jkl`. I want to trigger the alert and notifications when any of them get past threshold value of `2`. I don't want to alert when aggregated they surpass threshold limit rather individually.

Let's say if `abc.pqr` has `0` errors but `abc.jkl` has `3` errors then I should get the alert something like `abc.jkl has high error rate` and nothing about `abc.pqr`.

When I tried to aggregate by the `Add Query` option I get the final query like this

```
sum(last_10m):avg:trace.trace.annotation.errors{env:stage,service:xyz-stage,resource_name:abc.pqr}.as_count() + avg:trace.trace.annotation.errors{env:stage,service:xyz-stage,resource_name:abc.jkl}.as_count() > 2
```

When I tried to choose OR and adding more options after `from` then the final query is like this.

```
sum(last_10m):avg:trace.trace.annotation.errors{env:stage AND service:xyz-stage AND resource_name:abc.pqr OR env:stage AND service:xyz-stage AND resource_name:abc.jkl}.as_count() > 2
```

I don't think any of this is a valid query for what I am trying to achieve. Is this even possible in datadog or do I have to create separate monitors for both the metrics even though they have the same threshold value?

Answer (score 0):

you can create 2 separate monitoring and then unify those into one COMPOSITE MONITORING